# Swift Conversion of Objective C object to Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Code:

```
DBmanager *objDB;
objDB=[[DBManagers alloc]initWithDatabaseFilename:@"DB-8"];
```

Above is my line of code which needed to be convert into Swift.. I have linked my `DBmanger` Objective C class with new swift project.. now don't know how to do that...

Comment: is it `DBmanager` or `DBManagers`? - you use both here.

Comment: Actually i have typed wrong. it was DBmanager..

Comment: sure you don't mean `DBManager`? as in the answer? #itsnoteasy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing:

```
let objDB = DBManager(databaseFilename: "DB-8")
```

As soon as you start typing `DBManager(`, Xcode should show you available initializers.